Can you save a pdf/jpg/png as an object and arrange in a single plot?
I know how to save a plot as a pdf to disk ...
pdf(file = "sample.pdf")
plot(x=1:2,y=1:2)
dev.off()

But, instead of sample.pdf could I make the pdf an object in the global environment? I want to arbitrarily resize some plots and combine them in a grid. I can do it by saving the plots to disk and applying Imagemagick ... but how can I skip the export and reimport steps?

Could you maybe do what you want with the gridExtra package, without having to save your plots as image first?

Yes, gridExtra has a width argument! I'll try it

See help(“layout”) and help(“pdf”).

You can use layout. (gridExtra is designed for ggplot2 which works with "grids".)
> pdf('sample.pdf', 6, 4)  ## open pdf device
> op <- par(mar=c(4, 4, 1, 1))  ## set margins
> layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 1, 3), nrow=2))  ## define device layout
> # layout.show(3)  ## show layout for three plots
> plot(1:10)
> plot(1:10, col=2)
> plot(1:10, col=3)
> layout(1)  ## reset layout
> par(op)  ## reset pars
> dev.off()  ## close device
RStudioGD 
        2 


Note, that layout isn't compatible with par(mfrow), par(mfcol) and split.screen.
Alternatively use split.screen which can be very flexible.
> pdf('sample.pdf', 6, 4)  ## open pdf device
> op <- par(mar=c(4, 4, 1, 1))  ## set margins
> split.screen(matrix(c(
+   0, 1, 0.38, 1,   # Top full-width screen
+   0, 0.62, 0, 0.38, # Bottom-left screen
+   0.62, 1, 0, 0.38  # Bottom-right screen
+ ), ncol=4, byrow=TRUE))
[1] 1 2 3
> screen(1)
> plot(1:10)
> screen(2)
> plot(1:10, col=2)
> screen(3)
> plot(1:10, col=3)
> close.screen(all=TRUE)  ## Close all screens
> par(op)  ## reset pars
> dev.off()  ## close pdf device
RStudioGD 
        2 


Note, that split.screen() isn't compatible with par(mfrow), par(mfcol) and layout().
For easy stuff you can also use par(mfrow).
> op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
> plot(1:10)
> plot(1:10, col=2)
> par(op)

Can I save a base plot as an object?
Base plots are directly drawn in the device and thus can't be saved in an object. But you can create functions,
> my_plot <- \() {
+   plot(1:10)
+   lines((1:5)*2, c(7.8, 7, 4.2, 7.9, 4.9), col=2)
+   ## and more complicated stuff
+   ## w/ many lines
+ }

and use them concisely in the device.
> pdf('sampl.pdf')
> my_plot()
> dev.off()
RStudioGD 
        2 

